# Clear conversation session parameters in Google Action

Tags: typescript, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

In my conversation action, I have a scene in which the user is asked for a parameter. When I want to use that parameter I retrieve it that way:

```
const parameter = conv.scene.slots
    ? conv.scene.slots["parameterName"]?.value
    : "";
```

It works perfectly well on a first loop, but I want to give an opportunity to pick another value to the user. In the flow chart in scenes, I transition to the same scene when `MEDIA_STATUS_FINISHED is triggered` but instead of asking for filling the slot conversation already has this slot value in a session parameters list and plays that same mp3s as it seems that `scene.slots.status == "FINAL"` is matched.

How can I clear those parameters? Conversation object is immutable so do I have to clone it with empty session storage somehow, or is there a better way?

I want to achieve something like here on `Again`

https://youtu.be/Z1hxvniJ18s?t=2495

But I use backend service and add upon conversation instead of using prompts